# Enable XeTeX for LyX

Tags: xetex, lyx

I am trying to enable XeLaTeX for LyX, but I have some problems. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and LyX 2.0. I followed [an online tutorial in order to install XeTeX](http://modopemat.info/r/index.php?title=Install_LaTeX/XeTeX_and_xgreek_in_Ubuntu_9.10_(via_TeX_Live_2009)).

Then I opened LyX, but I can't enable the option to "use non TeX fonts via XeTeX/LuaTeX":

[image: screenshot]

ps1: LyX's interface is in Greek language

ps2: I have to enable first this option and then use a code in preamble in order to use a font right? :roll:

Comment: I don't suppose there's much chance you'll see this ... Can you double check that TeXlives binaries is actually in your path, *e.g.*, by running `pdflatex -v` in a terminal? I just installed TeXlive on Mint (without doing step 1.4 and 1.5 in your tutorial), and, prior to installing LyX, ran `equivs` as described [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html). Using system fonts in LyX worked fine then.

Comment: Under Ubuntu (12.04 now) I've installed xetex via `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex` and it works just fine.